# Sikuli not able to find the icons in the Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

Sikuli is not finding the icon in the unity launcher . I used the click function and in brackets the screen shot of the icon , but when the sikuli runs it's giving an error like `[error] FindFailed ( icon.png: (45x54) in S(0)[0,0 1920x950] E:Y, T:3.0 )`. Sikuli is able to find everything from the screen except the unity launcher icons(Tray icons also it is able to find).

Comment: What is "sikuli"?

Comment: The automation tool used in linux based systems. GUI automation we can do using sikuli

Comment: You can try to use other dock such as Plank.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and how did you installed SikuliX?

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 i installed sikulix. I installed using `apt-get install sikulix`